# Are there any stream combinator libraries for dart?

Tags: dart

Does anyone know of any stream combinator libraries for dart? Things like joining multiple Stream into one Stream, split, combine(Stream, Stream) -> Stream<(A, B)>, etc.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571924/how-can-i-merge-multiple-streams-into-a-higher-level-stream

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a stream combinator library, but you could try to use `StreamController` to join streams.

```
Stream join(Stream a, Stream b) {
  var sc = new StreamController();
  int countDone = 0;
  done() {
    countDone++;
    if (countDone == 2) {
      sc.close();
    }
  }
  a.listen((e) => sc.add(e), onDone: done);
  b.listen((e) => sc.add(e), onDone: done);

  return sc.stream;
}
```

Warning: untested code.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I wrote, but there are problems that I pointed out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17018427/dart-how-do-i-implement-stream-join-that-preserves-the-order-of-incoming-items/17019119?noredirect=1#comment24596762_17019119

Answer (score 1):

Check out my library [Frappe](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/frappe). It's loosely inspired by Bacon.js, and has a bunch of methods for combining streams.