# dart: how do I implement stream join that preserves the order of incoming items?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to implement a join operator that takes a list of Streams and outputs a single stream. The problem is the output order is not the same as the input order. StreamController.add is asynchronous, so if I do

```
sc1.add(1)
sc2.add(2)
sc2.add(3)
sc2.add(4)
sc1.add(5)
...
```

the order in which the respective stream ondata callbacks get invoked is something like 1,2,5,3,4 which is basically an interleaving of sc1 and sc2. This ordering is pretty consistent across executions, which leads me to believe the implementation is doing round robin dispatch on a single thread. (this is on dart VM)

If the ordering is already scrambled by the time the ondata callback is called in my join implementation, I can't implement this join correctly. Does anyone have good ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: what SDK version is this?

Comment: I'm using sdk version 0.5.13r23552

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are using some recent version of the SDK.

`sync` flag was introduced for `SteamController` constructors since v0.5.11, and it  controls this behavior (see docs [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html#StreamController) and [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html#StreamController.broadcast)). By default it is set to `false`, which means that listeners are called asynchronously, i.e. some time after the `add` call has finished:

> If sync is false, no guarantees are given with regard to when multiple
>   listeners get the events, except that each listener will get all
>   events in the correct order. If two events are sent on an async
>   controller with two listeners, one of the listeners may get both
>   events before the other listener gets any

If you don't own the controllers, then I am not sure if there is much you can do.

Comment: I wonder if this is why there is no standard join combinator as part of some public library. In the test cases I own the controllers, but this won't be true in general.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the reason, as this change was introduced just a few days ago (and it broke all the tests in my event library :), but it surely complicates things for such scenarios. OTOH, if you already have 2 async stream controllers, you could argue that ordering should not be strict anyway.

Comment: good point. I haven't thought through all the implications of moving to async streams vs using conventional event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

`add` is only synchronous if the StreamController is created with the named parameter `sync` and value `true`.

http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html#StreamController