# How we can mix streams in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

Let Two Stream deliver two different types of data.
I want a one stream from those two stream that combine the data and wrap in data class and delivers it.

Example:

```
Stream<String> stream1;
Stream<String> stream2;

class Data{
    String s1;
    String s2;
    Data(this.s1,this.s2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no "out of the box" solution for this. You typically have to create custom logic for this (called `StreamTransformer`).

You can use 3rd party libraries on the other hand. Such as `rxdart`, which includes multiples stream fusions operators:

```
Stream<String> stream1;
Stream<String> stream2;
Stream<String> concat = Observable.combineLatest2(stream1, stream2, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Comment: and what about `StreamGroup`? i never used it but the docs seem to say that it is a stream multiplexer

Comment: Ah well, it's not shipped with dart SDK and requires all stream values to have the same type

Comment: ```StreamGroup.merge([stream1, stream1]).map((event) {
   //event will be of type Object if the type aren't the same
   return event;
});```

Answer (score 0):

Use stream transform function **combineLatest** from the stream_transform package (add dependency to "stream_transform" in pubspec.yml).

```
import 'package:stream_transform/stream_transform.dart' show combineLatest;

Stream<Data> combinedStream(Stream<String> stream1, Stream<String> stream2) {
  return stream1.transform(combineLatest(stream2, (s1, s2) => Data(s1, s2)));
}
```

Also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912217/3635696 (without telling how to access the combineLastest function).

Comment: try adding some of your attachment into your answer to give it more quality.