# How to merge streams in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query 2 collections from firebase and put it in a `streambuilder`.
There are lot of questions like this,but a lot of them are unsolved,or I just didn't really found the right one.

So,I got a `users`,and a `salons` collection in Firebase.
`user1` contains his name,age,etc and he have another collection called `favsalons`. In `salons` are the description of salons like name,owner,etc
In app I want to list out the `favsalons` with their datas.

In SQL it would look something like this : `Select salons.name,salons.owner From salons,user Where userID=user1 and favsalonsID=salonsID` 
Since I'm new to flutter,and to the non SQL databases,I got no clue how to do it.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571924/how-can-i-merge-multiple-streams-into-a-higher-level-stream, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7EaYUIRBmc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with simply nesting two `streambuilders`.

Comment: jajajajaja That's not merging!

Comment: @Bojke could you show how you did that, i have a problem like this, i have a colection of object that references another object in another collection by key/id, now i just want to know how join to get for each object get its relationed object in the other colletion.

Comment: @JorgeVieira used 2 streambuilders like when you for example nest 2 for loops,then used a loop to filter the snapshots,and put it in a list.

Comment: Providing more details to your answer would have been really useful.

Comment: @Bojke can you share your code? I couldn't build the structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can't... You need to modify the structure of your data.
Watch the firebase team [explanation.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKEhWAV-kE)

Comment: So I have to duplicate to all users every salon he likes?