# How to create a Stream followed by another Stream?

Tags: dart, stream

In Dart, there's a handy `followedBy` method for `List`s:

```dart
[1, 2].followedBy([3, 4]) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is there anything like that for `Stream`s?

I'm looking for something like this:

```dart
Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]).followedBy(otherStream);
```

I already looked at the `async` package, but `StreamZip`, `StreamGroup` and `StreamQueue` don't seem to be what I want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571924/how-can-i-merge-multiple-streams-into-a-higher-level-stream/36574707 maybe?

Comment: Already seen that, but they always combine the latest two elements of the streams. What I want to do is to first use up all the elements of the first stream/list and only then using those of the second stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably something more efficient, but this will work.

```
Stream<int> streams() async* {
   yield* stream1();
   yield* stream2();
}
```